# XPath concat with EXTRACT function Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, extract, concatenation

I want to extract the values of "KEY" and "VALUE" and concat these results using XPath with EXTRACT.

Sample XML as below.

```
<PivotSet>
  <item>
    <column name = "KEY">RET_1</column>
    <column name = "VALUE">A</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name = "KEY">RET_2</column>
    <column name = "VALUE">R</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name = "KEY">RET_3</column>
    <column name = "VALUE">P</column>
  </item>
</PivotSet>
```

I need to return in SQL something like

```
RET_1@A;RET_2@R;RET_3@P
```

where the delimiter '@' separates the key/value and ':' separates the items. I want to do it with EXTRACT and XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListAgg along with an XmlTable, see below:

```
select LISTAGG(keyItem || '@' || keyValue, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY keyItem) AS Concated
from XmlTable( '/PivotSet/item' PASSING XmlType('<PivotSet>
  <item>
    <column name = "KEY">RET_1</column>
    <column name = "VALUE">A</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name = "KEY">RET_2</column>
    <column name = "VALUE">R</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name = "KEY">RET_3</column>
    <column name = "VALUE">P</column>
  </item>
</PivotSet>') COLUMNS keyItem PATH '*:column[@name = "KEY"]',
                      keyValue PATH '*:column[@name = "VALUE"]');
```

You could use ExtractValue, but you would need to know how many `//item` elements are in your XML and then indicate in your path portion of the extract call, but this is a little messy IMO:

```
SELECT ExtractValue(xmlOut, '//item[1]/column[@name="KEY"]') || '@' || ExtractValue(xmlOut, '//item[1]/column[@name="VALUE"]') || ';' ||
       ExtractValue(xmlOut, '//item[2]/column[@name="KEY"]') || '@' || ExtractValue(xmlOut, '//item[2]/column[@name="VALUE"]') || ';' ||
       ExtractValue(xmlOut, '//item[3]/column[@name="KEY"]') || '@' || ExtractValue(xmlOut, '//item[3]/column[@name="VALUE"]')  As Concatted
FROM
(
    SELECT XmlType('<PivotSet>
  <item>
    <column name = "KEY">RET_1</column>
    <column name = "VALUE">A</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name = "KEY">RET_2</column>
    <column name = "VALUE">R</column>
  </item>
  <item>
    <column name = "KEY">RET_3</column>
    <column name = "VALUE">P</column>
  </item>
</PivotSet>') as xmlOut FROM dual
);
```